# How do I keep my screen from going dim when idle?

Tags: unity, 11.10, gnome, power-management

Apparently, the new version of Unity is based on Gnome 3. Apparently, Gnome 3 decided to do away with a huge chunk of the options available to me.

It used to be that when I went to System Settings -> Power Settings, I could keep my screen from going dim when idle -- and things like that. Is there any way for me to change those settings now? Or am I doomed to have my screen go dim when I let my computer go for five seconds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its now under **System settings -> Screen**

[image]